# page not found for opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to download openCV4android but it seems that the server is down at: http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

[image]

from where can i download it?

Comment: The server is not down.  You just went to a page that does not exist.  Try http://opencv.org/platforms/android/

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock thanks!